# Is any better syntax to perform this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Below is my code

```
    if(!chineseName) {
        alert("chineseName is not correct");
    }
    else if(!IDN){
        alert("IDN is not correct");
    }
    else if(!mobileNumber){
        alert("number is not correct");
    }
    else if(hasAccount){
        if(!isAccountNumberValid) {
            alert("account number is not correct");
        }
        else {
            check();
        }
    }
    else {
        check();
    }



    function check() {
        if(!check1 && !check2) {
            alert("Please read NOTE and check the read box.");
        }
        else {
            alert("Everything is good to go!!");
        }
    }
```

Now, this code is working correct.
However, I would like to know if there any better syntax to perform same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: You should move your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just a friendly reminder you might wanna post this question to codereview.stackexchange.com before somebody makes it irrelevant here and you get a lot of down votes. Happened to me.

Comment: Sorry , I did not know we have that place.Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code review request.

Comment: There might be a better way to do the same, can you post complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the last two else because the action is the same, simply changing the last if condition.

```
if (!chineseName) {
    alert("chineseName is not correct");
} else if (!IDN){
    alert("IDN is not correct");
} else if (!mobileNumber){
    alert("number is not correct");
} else if (hasAccount && !isAccountNumberValid) {  // Modified condition
    alert("account number is not correct");
} else {
    check();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably consolidate all the alerts into one:

```
var msg = "";

if (!chineseName) {
    msg = "chineseName is not correct";
} else if (!IDN) {
    msg = "IDN is not correct";
} else if (!mobileNumber) {
    msg = "number is not correct";
} else if (hasAccount) {
    if (!isAccountNumberValid) {
        msg = "account number is not correct";
    } else {
        msg = check();
    }
} else {
    msg = check();
}

alert(msg);


function check() {
    if (!check1 && !check2)
        return "Please read NOTE and check the read box.";

    return "Everything is good to go!!";
}
```